# Error while running python program

Tags: python

I am running the code for pyzillow and I am encountering the following problem while importing the django library.

from django.contrib.gis.geos.error import GEOSException

**ImportError: No module named django.contrib.gis.geos.error**

Thoughts?

Comment: Post the code in your question please

Answer (score 0):

Follow the Django Docs,
find this line in settings and make it like this- 
GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = r'C:\Program Files\OSGeo4W64\bin\geos_c.dll'

This will solve the issue